# About CAML and its content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml

Problem:
I have understood the foundation of CAML and there are some questions that are still unclear in my mind.

1. What context and when should a SP developer use CAML?
2. Why using CAML to retrieve data? what about stored procedure?
3. How common is it for a SP developer to use CAML?
4. Do you have a real based example when you used CAML?

Answer (score 3):

CAML can be used in various ways to customize a SharePoint site, including the following:

- In script or code that implements members of the SharePoint
  Foundation object model, where CAML strings are passed through method
  parameters, assigned to properties, or returned by methods and
  properties
- In SOAP messaging that passes CAML strings to a SharePoint Foundation
  Web service to interact remotely with a deployment
- In front-end site definitions used to instantiate SharePoint sites
- In SharePoint Foundation Features to add specific functionality
  within a particular scope
  For supported SharePoint artificacts, always use CAML unless there is a reason not to.
  Use this link for [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms426449.aspx) details.